# Kerberos and Integrated Security using jTDS Driver

Tags: java, kerberos, jtds, apache-commons-dbcp, integrated-security

Up till now we were using MS JDBC Driver 4.0 to connect to SQL Server 2008 using Integrated Security and Java Kerberos and everything was working fine.

Here is the code:

***Spring Context:***

```
<!-- ***** Data Source Configuration ***** -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
    <property name="url"
        value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<serverName>:<port>;databaseName=<DBName>;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos; />
    <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="2" />
    <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" />
</bean>

<!-- ***** Transaction Manager ***** -->
<bean id="txManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />

<!-- ***** JDBC Configuration ***** -->
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg type="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

***login.conf File:***

```
com.sun.security.jgss.krb5.initiate {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
   useTicketCache=false
   doNotPrompt=true
   useKeyTab=true
   keyTab="C:/myKeyTABFile"
   principal="me@org.foo.com"
   storeKey=true
   debug=true
};
```

***krb5.conf File:***

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = org.foo.com
    dns_lookup_realm = false
    dns_lookup_kdc = true
    ticket_lifetime = 1s
    forwardable = yes
    #udp_preference_limit = 1

[realms]
    org.foo.com = {
      kdc = org.foo.com
      default_domain = org.foo.com
    }

[domain_realm]
    .org.foo.com = org.foo.com

[login]
    krb4_convert = true
    krb4_get_tickets = false
```

We were passing following arguments while running the Project:

```
-Djava.security.krb5.debug=true 
-Djava.security.auth.login.config="C:\login.conf" 
-Djava.security.krb5.conf="C:\krb5.conf
```

Now, we decided to use jTDS instead of MS JDBC Driver and I made following changes in the above configuration:

1. Changed Driver class from `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver` to `net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver`
2. Changed Connection String from `jdbc:sqlserver://...` to `jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://...`
3. Added jTDS JAR and NTLM Authentication DLL File(s) to the Classpath

But it is giving me the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException:
>   Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (I/O Error: GSS Failed: No
>   valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any
>   Kerberos tgt))    at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
>     at org.foo.utils.Foo.main(Foo.java:51)
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: GSS Failed: No valid
>   credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos
>   tgt)  at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.login(TdsCore.java:654)    at
>   net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.(JtdsConnection.java:371)
>     at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184)    at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
>     ... 3 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: GSS Failed: No valid
>   credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos
>   tgt)  at
>   net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.sendMSLoginPkt(TdsCore.java:1976)
>     at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.login(TdsCore.java:617)    ... 9
>   more

Things I have already tried:

1. Tried appending `useKerberos=true;` and `useNTLMv2=true;` to the Connection String
2. Tried appending `domain=org.foo.com` to the Connection String

But it does not seems to be working. I tried searching on internet but could not find any solution.

Would appreciate if someone could help me out.

Comment: Why did you change the driver?

Comment: Because we saw a huge performance improvement using jTDS as compared to the MS JDBC.

Comment: Thanks for this information. Il ultimately means that Microsoft is a terrible database vendor and does not care about other usecases than Windows....

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After searching and trying different combinations and looking at the source code of jTDS this is what finally worked for me.

1. Use property `useKerberos=true` in the Connection String

   **Source:** https://sourceforge.net/p/jtds/patches/101/
2. Pass VM Argument `-Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false`

So, finally after applying the above changes my Connection String looked like below:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<serverName>:<port>;databaseName=<DBName>;useKerberos=true;
```

Arguments List:

```
-Djava.security.krb5.debug=true 
-Djava.security.auth.login.config="C:\login.conf" 
-Djava.security.krb5.conf="C:\krb5.conf
-Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the working recipe. I am still looking, how we can configure Kerbros in Linux